# AppsFlyer returns status code 400

Tags: android, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

I implemented Appsflyer for my sample project, but when I run it, the server returns an error code 400.

```
I/AppsFlyer_1.18-117182240: response code: 400
```

There is my `MainActivty.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String LOG_TAG = "AppsFlyerSampleApp";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    // Set the Currency
    AppsFlyerLib.setCurrencyCode("USD");

    // The Dev key cab be set here or in the manifest.xml
    AppsFlyerLib.setAppsFlyerKey("aaaa");
    AppsFlyerLib.sendTracking(this);

    AppsFlyerLib.registerConversionListener(this, new AppsFlyerConversionListener() {
        public void onInstallConversionDataLoaded(Map<String, String> conversionData) {
            DebugLogQueue.getInstance().push("\nGot conversion data from server");
            for (String attrName : conversionData.keySet()) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "attribute: " + attrName + " = " + conversionData.get(attrName));
            }
        }

        public void onInstallConversionFailure(String errorMessage) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error getting conversion data: " + errorMessage);
        }

        public void onAppOpenAttribution(Map<String, String> attributionData) {
            printMap(attributionData);
        }

        public void onAttributionFailure(String errorMessage) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error onAttributionFailure : " + errorMessage);

        }

        private void printMap(Map<String, String> map) {
            for (String key : map.keySet()) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, key + "=" + map.get(key));
            }

        }
    });
}
```

And my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.afapplication">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="appsflyer" />
            <!--<data android:scheme="http"-->
            <!--android:host="sometest.com"  />-->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I don't know why the server outputs an error code 400?
Has anyone else got a similar case?

Comment: Do you know what this error means? It says that your request ist bad. So check what your are sending.

Comment: Thanks Thomas R. I know this error mean. But the request send auto built by Appsflyer.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set some data? Or corrupt data?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Just wait ~20min after creation of your new app at Appsflyer console

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check your applicationId and make sure that you have created your app with the same applicationId in the Appsflyer dashboard.

I had the same error code until I found a typo in the applicationId I entered to create my test app on Appsflyer...

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

After hours of search, I found my solution.

I was not Using correct Appsflyer key. There are two keys

1. API Key : Integration -> API Access -> Your API Key
2. Dev Key : Configuration -> App Setting -> SDK Installation

Use the dev key for checking out the installations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Build and Run in `Release` variant. Also set `debuggable true` just to make sure AppsFlyer works and you can see installation logs in Logcat

Answer (score 0):

400 indicates something goes wrong with your dev key or application id. Turn on AF debug log by `AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().setDebugLog(true);`, and check if the key and id in request urls match the ones on your appsflyer dashboard.

note: the key and id in your code would not natually matche the ones the app uses to generate request urls, since they can be modified elsewhere in your code, so you need to check the request urls in log